# Expressions describing discount

Tags: word-choice, expressions

may I ask if the following expressions describing discount sound natural? Many thanks!

A) to rent a house with a discount of 20% off

B) to rent a house with a 20% off discount

C) to rent a house with 80% discount

D) to rent a house at 80% market price

E) To rent a house for 80% of the market fee

F) To rent a house for 80% market fee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"to rent a house with a 20% **discount**".  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/discount)

> To reduce in quantity or value: discount a price.

discount and off are redundant

Comment: Noted with thanks, ibf! Then how about the expressions D, E, and F?(In case the word 'discount' is not preferred) Do they sound natural to native speakers?

Comment: D would be best

Comment: Note that D sounds like the price a renter would pay to the landlord while E sounds like the amount a landlord would pay to a rental agent.